# Как я могу пропускать чтение кадров CV2 с устройства?

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

Видеопоток cv2 грузит процессор на 10%. Мне не нужны все 15 или 30 кадров/c с камеры. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу не читать такие кадры снизив следовательно нагрузку на процессор? Я бы мог их просто не обрабатывать, но мне все равно приходилось бы их читать. Есть какие-нибудь варианты? Я бы хотел считывать к примеру каждый 5 кадр

https://pastebin.com/fF90NwVc

Comment: Это технически невозможно, для построения любого неключевого кадра используется информация из предыдущих (а иногда даже следующих) кадров

Comment: Единственное, что возможно - оставить только ключевые кадры, но они обычно появляются один раз в 5-10 секунд, что скорее всего будет для вас слишком мало

Comment: @andreymal Здравствуйте! Спасибо большое за ответы. Я вообще ничего не смогу сделать? Т е мне в любом случае нужно будет запускать последовательно .read() и получать все кадры?

Comment: @andreymal это для h264 актуальны ключевые кадры да и cv2 должна фрейм отдать уже декодированный.

Comment: @eri а вот оказалсь, что автора сетевая камера и rtsp-поток, внутри которого с 99% вероятностью h264 :)

Comment: @andreymail я должен это указать в строке rstp подключения?  rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.1.216

Comment: @Allen с сетевой камерой вы ничего не сделаете, кому-то где-то неизбежно придётся декодировать все кадры из rtsp-h264 потока. Если камера умеет отдавать jpeg-кадры по http, можно попытаться забирать их вместо использования rtsp, но это тоже добавляет своего геморроя

Comment: кстати задача то какая? может тут и cv не нужен?

Comment: @eri  я собираюсь сохранять кадры на диск, а после отправлять их в систему распознавания. что я могу в итоге сделать, ничего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например для каждого 10 кадра(3 fps из 30) пропускай лишние когда читаешь:

```
import cv2

def process_frame(frame):
    pass

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i = 0
while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if i == 0:
        process_frame(frame)
    i += 1
    i %= 10
  
vid.release()
```

При этом можно снять нагрузку с камеры. Запусти `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` или другую программу для камеры  - посмотри доступные fps (моя может 5,7.5,10,15,20,25,30)

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 5)
```

и с `i %= 5` получишь один кадр в секунду

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. vcap.get(5) показывает 15 кадров на входе. у меня сетевая камера ezviz c1c-b. установка входного fps будет работать для меня? rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.1.216 - вот моя строка подключения

Comment: напишите в вопросе как забираете с неё кадры. vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 5) не прокатит, но остатком от деления всёже можно пропускать ненужные кадры.

Comment: Я добавил ссылку на код

Comment: я не вижу что вы с кадром что-то делаете.

Comment: Я там с кадром пока ничего не делаю. вопрос был в нагрузке при получении кадра, так как если считывать все кадры проц грузит на 10%, в методе update_and_save я добавлю сохранение кадров на диск. И хотел бы сохранять каждый 6 кадр, при входном fps 30, например

Comment: тут либо я снижаю нагрузку и получаю просто каждый 6 кадр, либо читаю все, нагрузка в 10% остается и должен как-то считать кадры, чтобы брать каждый 6

Comment: fps входного потока можно получить. Пусть будет 30 кадров в секунду. То есть 1 кадр это 1/30 секунды. перед считыванием нужно получить время в секундах (микросекундах), добавить к нему 5/30 секунды если считывать каждый пятый. Перед считыванием следующего кадра вычислить сколько времени нужно подождать и сделать sleep

Comment: @pb318 а разве там нет курсора или буфера? и я получу следующий по порядку доступный в памяти кадр

Comment: Нет. Можно попробовать - вставить sleep на 1 секунду в любом случае. Я пробовал грузить видеопоток с камеры тяжелыми вычислениями (распознавание лиц сторонними алгоритмами) - просто проседал fps, программа обрабатывала столько кадров, сколько успевала.

Comment: sleep неправильное решение.

Comment: курсор или буфер проходит по декодированным кадрам - тоесть нагрузка останется...

Comment: надо попробовать поставить хук до декодирования и потаскать ключевые кадры)

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2

videofile = 't1-720-30-21s.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videofile)
shift = 5  
frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
frame = 0
while frame < frames:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame)
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frameshift', img)
    frame += shift
    key_press = cv2.waitKeyEx(10)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

shift - выводить каждый пятый кадр
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame) - позиционирует ввод на конкретный фрейм

Comment: Это не совсем то, что спрашивалось. Здесь считывание видеопотока происходит из файла с видео, а не с камеры.
При считывании с камеры fps камеры не учитывается. Либо программа успевает считывать и обрабатывать весь видеопоток с частотой кадров, который дает камера, либо то, что успевает, то есть не каждый кадр, а текущий, который есть на входе.
Разгрузить процессор можно либо элементарным time.sleep (чать кадров будет пропускаться), либо обработку кадров запускать отдельными процессами с помощью multiprocessing